# How to obtain the target element on click event in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I want the exact target on which the click event has been triggered in ASP.NET Core blazor. Is this achievable?

Comment: Pass the id to your event handller

Comment: if you need more than agua from mars's pointer.Then this question is light on details, if you want to be more specific I will try to help you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use @ref to get a reference to a DOM object, then pass it as a parameter to your handler function.

You can then pass it as a parameter to the JS Interop.

For example:

Counter.razor

```cs
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<p>Last button clicked: @lastButtonClicked</p>

<button @ref=button1 class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(()=>IncrementCount(@button1))">Click me</button>
<button @ref=button2 class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(()=>IncrementCount(@button2))">Click me</button>


@code {

    private ElementReference button1;
    private ElementReference button2;

    private int currentCount = 0;
    private string lastButtonClicked = "None";

    private async void IncrementCount(ElementReference element)
    {
        currentCount++;
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setElementText", element, "I was clicked");
    }
}
```

And make sure to add this script to Index.html

```html
<script>
    window.setElementText = (element, text) => { console.log(element); element.innerText = text; }
</script>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.1#detect-when-a-blazor-app-is-prerendering

Answer (score 1):

In .razor file:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    <input type="text" @onchange='eventargs => HandleValueChange(eventargs, "my first textbox from row " + j.ToString())' />
    <input type="text" @onchange='eventargs => HandleValueChange(eventargs, "my second textbox from row " + j.ToString())' />
}

@code {
    protected void HandleValueChange(ChangeEventArgs evt, string elementID)
    {

    }
}
```

Note: The key here is the int j = i declaration in the inner-loop scope ... if you pass i to the event handler you will always get '1000' i.e. it's final value from the outer loop scope

Comment: This is `onchange`, the question is about `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

In case you dont need ElementReference but just wont to use the clicked element inside JavaScript, Blazor wasm:

When you call any function using js interop after the click you will be surprised to find a defined variable `event` (you don't have to pass anything to the function), containing the info about the click, the target element will be obviously inside `event.target`.

If you know why this works this way please edit this answer. It looks like just a miracle.. :)

Comment: This is not Blazor functionality. What you are accessing is actually the global [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) value that is set by the browser. If multiple events are triggered at the same time, this value will be whatever event was last, so it might not be the event you actually want. It's also deprecated.